# Complex numbers: Find the sum of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(2-i)}{(1-i)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

I have come up with a solution but I am not sure if it is correct. Here is what I have so far:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(2-i)}{(1-i)^n}$$
$$= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(1-i)^n} - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{i}{(1-i)^n}$$

Now, let's assume that $S_n$ is the partial sum of the first $n$ terms of the series:
$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(1-i)^n}$$
Then:

$$S_1 = \frac{2}{(1-i)}$$
$$S_2 = \frac{2}{(1-i)} + \frac{2}{(1-i)^2}  = \frac{2(1-i)+2}{(1-i)^2}$$
$$S_3 = \frac{2}{(1-i)} + \frac{2}{(1-i)^2} + \frac{2}{(1-i)^3} = \frac{2(1-i)^2 + 2(1-i) + 2}{(1-i)^3}$$
I can see that the pattern is:
When $n \geq 2$:
$$S_n = \frac{2(1-i)^{n-1} + 2(1-i)^{n-2} + ... + 2(1-i) + 2}{(1-i)^n} $$
When $n = 1 $:
$$S_1 = \frac{2}{(1-i)}$$

For the series:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{i}{(1-i)^n}$$
the same concept applies, as such:
When 
$n \geq 2$:
$$S_n = \frac{i(1-i)^{n-1} + i(1-i)^{n-2} + ... + i(1-i) + i}{(1-i)^n} $$
When $n = 1 $:
$$S_1 = \frac{i}{(1-i)}$$

So, we have:

$$= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(1-i)^n} - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{i}{(1-i)^n}$$
$$= \frac{2}{(1-i)} + \frac{2(1-i)^{n-1} + 2(1-i)^{n-2} + ... + 2(1-i) + 2}{(1-i)^n} - \frac{i}{(1-i)} - \frac{i(1-i)^{n-1} + i(1-i)^{n-2} + ... + i(1-i) + i}{(1-i)^n} $$
(For the limits, I will ignore the lesser order terms.)
$$ = \frac{2}{(1-i)} + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{2(1-i)^{n-1}}{(1-i)^n}}- \frac{i}{1-i} - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{i(1-i)^{n-1}}{(1-i)^n}}$$ 
$$= \frac{2}{1-i} + \frac{2}{1-i} - \frac{i}{1-i} - \frac{i}{1-i}$$
(From complex division)
$$ = \frac{6+2i}{2}$$
$$= 3 + i$$

Is this correct or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D1+to+infinity+(2-i)%2F(1-i)%5En

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made things WAY too hard for yourself.

This is a geometric series, with initial term $a=\frac{2-i}{1-i}$ and common ratio $r=\frac{1}{1-i}$.  So, as long as $\lvert r\rvert<1$, we know that the series will converge to $\frac{a}{1-r}$.

In this case,
$$
\lvert r\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{1}{1-i}\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{1+i}{2}\right\rvert=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}<1.
$$
So, we know that the series converges to
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{1-r}&=\frac{\left(\frac{2-i}{1-i}\right)}{1-\frac{1}{1-i}}\\
&=\frac{2-i}{1-i-1}\\
&=\frac{2-i}{-i}\\
&=1+2i.
\end{align*}
$$